# perl Hash Data Type list order

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
%mylist=("svrmlb"=>"10.0.0.1","svrcmb"=>"10.0.0.2","svrkdy"=>"10.0.0.3");

print("key-val\n");
for $x (keys(%mylist))
{
    print ("$x:$mylist{$x}\n");
}

print("\nvals\n");
for $x (values(%mylist))
{
    print ("$x\n");
}
```

When I compile the above code I get the following output

```
key-val
svrcmb:10.0.0.2
svrkdy:10.0.0.3
svrmlb:10.0.0.1

vals
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.1
```

But my expected output was

```
 key-val
 svrmlb:10.0.0.1
 svrcmb:10.0.0.2
 svrkdy:10.0.0.3

 vals
 10.0.0.1
 10.0.0.2
 10.0.0.3
```

My problem is why did it get sorted, I didn't apply sort to either keys or values. Is this is a characteristic of hash? Earlier I've tried to sort few other hashed arrays and they weren't like this. Please help me to understand.

Comment: Run it several time, you'll probably have different outputs every time. That should answer your question.

Comment: yes the order is changing, that means the keys are not in the order they are entered to the list?

Comment: Re "*I didn't apply sort to either keys or values*", Exactly. You specified no order at all.

Comment: @ikegami now I get it tysm!!!

Answer (score 3):

As [perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata) says:

> Hashes are unordered collections of scalar values indexed by their associated string key.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two quick solutions:
1- store your Keys in an array;
2- use Tie::IxHash; (this is not usually installed by default)

```
%mylist=("svrmlb"=>"10.0.0.1","svrcmb"=>"10.0.0.2","svrkdy"=>"10.0.0.3");
@mylist=("svrmlb","svrcmb","svrkdy");

print("key-val\n");
for $x (@mylist)
{
    print ("$x:$mylist{$x}\n");
}

print("\nvals\n");
for $x (@mylist)
{
    print ("$mylist{$x}\n");
}
```

### use Tie::IxHash

```
use Tie::IxHash;
%mylist=("svrmlb"=>"10.0.0.1","svrcmb"=>"10.0.0.2","svrkdy"=>"10.0.0.3");
tie %mylist, 'Tie::IxHash';

print("key-val\n");
for $x (keys(%mylist))
{
    print ("$x:$mylist{$x}\n");
}

print("\nvals\n");
for $x (values(%mylist))
{
    print ("$x\n");
}
```